# Add related games within a category

Tags: php, mysql, random, include

I've been trying to add a section called: "related games", in it there is a script (related.php) that will fetch 5 random related games of the same category that the online game is displayed on.

I tried this (related.php):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['genre'])){

$game_category = $_GET['genre'];

$select_games = "SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,5";

$run_games = mysql_query($select_games);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_games)){

$game_id = $row['game_id'];
$game_name = $row['game_name'];
$game_image = $row['game_image'];
?>

<table>

<tr>
<div class="game_grid">
  <a href="game_page.php?id=<?php echo $game_id; ?>"><img src="images/games_images/<?php echo $game_image; ?>" width="120" height="120" />
  <span><?php echo $game_name; ?></span></a>
</div>
<tr>

</table>

<?php } } ?>
```

This is the "related.php" file and I tried to implement it in the following file called: "game_page.php" which works perfectly...

For some reason no random game is showing under the current played game...
Any idea?

Comment: You have to create a mysql connection, and then use that connection string in the mysql_query statement.  Furthermore, you should be using mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_*, as mysql_* has been deprecated.

Comment: Thats the point, There is a mysql connection on the "game_page.php" where I include this "related.php" file... I will convert everything to mysqli once the website is done completely.

Comment: Check if you are sending genre in query string ( get variable )

Comment: All the variables that are sitting in the "related.php" file are already assigned at the "game_page.php" file...

Comment: Change this line to this: $run_games = mysql_query($select_games, $conn);  You forgot your connection variable in mysql_query

Comment: Now the results are displaying vertical... how to display them horizontal?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it xD, I simply removed the

```
if(isset($_GET['genre'])){
$game_category = $_GET['genre'];
```

strings because they are already included in the "game_page.php" file :)